# How to distribute the .ipa by url without a paid developer account

Tags: xcode, ipa

I loaded a manifest file at server and I want to know can other people download application and use it or without payment account it's impossible.

I mean distribute by url.

Example
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://base.cloudfront.net/ios/test/manifest.plist

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know can other people download application and use it or without payment account it's impossible

Yes, it's impossible. The ability to distribute apps is one of the main things that a paid developer account buys you.